# symfony 1.4: How to get the assignated id (in the db of course..) of an embedded form's object?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

how to get the assignated id (in the db of course..) of an embedded form's object?

It's a 1:m relation.

Sf 1.4

Javi

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
echo $form->getEmbeddedForm('your_embedded_form_name')->getObject()->getId();
```